# how does javascript FileReader know which file to read?

Tags: javascript, filereader

Referring to this thread:
[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

I would like to know how simply calling `reader = new FileReader()` lets FileReader know which file to read.

The thread link posted above works just fine for me, but when I try the following, `FileReader()` does not read the input. `console.log` returns nothing.

Javascript:

```
function fileReader(input){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e){
    console.log(e.target.result);
  };
}

$(function(){
  $('#file').change(function(){
    fileReader(this);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="file" type="file">
```

Why doesn't this work?
Is there a way to manually give `FileReader()` which input DOM to read?

Comment: thanks for the question, I was starting to eat my nails because I also had the same question in my mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how simply calling reader = new FileReader() lets FileReader know which file to read.

It doesn't.

You missed this line from the answer of the question you linked to:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

Comment: is there a reason why it is written after onload function?

Comment: Setting event handlers before running operations that could trigger those event handlers is usual.